# Angular 2 Opening a different form with a passed in parameter

Tags: angular2-routing, angular2-forms

Hope someone can advise the best way to achieve what I want.

I have a user grid where you can click edit it then goes to the manage user form.

What I want to do is pass the selected user id over to the manage user form and display this user, how best would I go about achieving this?

Thanks
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `grid.component.html`, when user clicks on a grid edit button, call a function and pass the corresponding grid data id as shown below.

```
<button (click)="goToManageForm(gridId)"> Edit</button>
```

In your `grid.component.ts`, pass the id as a param to the manageForm component.

```
private goToManageForm(id:any){
   this.router.navigate([`/manageForm/${id}`]);
}
```

In your routing component, add a route to manageForm component which expects a parameter.

const routes: Routes = [

```
{
    path: '',
    component: MyMainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    children: [
      { path: 'grid',    component: GridComponent },
      { path: 'manageForm/:gridId',    component: ManageFormComponent },
]
}
```

You can access the passed grid id in the `manageForm.component.ts` as shown below.

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router,ActivatedRoute } from '@angular/router';
import { Subscription } from 'rxjs';

export class manageFormComponent {

   private subscription:Subscription;
   private gridId:any; 

   constructor(private activatedRoute:ActivatedRoute){}

   ngOnInit(): void {

      // subscribe to router event
      this.subscription = this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe(
        (param: any) => {
           if(typeof param['gridId'] !== 'undefined' && param['gridId'].trim !='' ){ 
              this.gridId = param['gridId'];
           }
      });
   }
 }
```

Now the passed gridId will be accessible in `this.gridId`

Comment: Hi Veena, thanks for the reply, I will get it a go and let you know how I get on

Comment: @stephenad pls feel free to ask me if you are stuck with any errors

Comment: Hi Veena thanks for your reply I have got this working so greatly appreciated, I do have a related follow up question should I open a new ticket for that?

Comment: I do have one issue I had to comment out the canActivate: [AuthGuard], line what do I need to get that to be accepted and work do I need a specific import?

Comment: @stephenad no, you do dont need any specific import for that. Pls go through this link https://angular.io/api/router/CanActivate . If you still have issues, pls open a ticket regarding the issue. Thanks :)